# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'day')

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```html
<div class="cont">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(value, key) in dayappointment.visit" :key="value">
            {{ key }}: {{ value }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="dayboxes">
            {{dayappointment.visit.day}}
        </div>
        <div class="dayboxes">
            {{dayappointment.visit.month}}
        </div>
        <div class="dayboxes">
            {{dayappointment.visit.year}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The unordered list shows the day, month, year keys and its values but they are somehow undefined in the day div.

Comment: Can you show the result of `JSON.stringify(this.dayappointment.visit)`?

Comment: {"day":4,"month":"JAN","year":2022}

Comment: Kindly share the script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 **somehow what was needed was to iterate the object like this**              
   <div class="day">
            <div v-for="(value) in dayappointment.visit" :key="value" 
             class="dayboxes">
                {{value}}
            </div>
        </div>
```